# How to add nav-active class in in navigation using jquery only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please help me to sort out this problem. I want to add `nav-active` class in li element only one time means if child element is selected then parent li should not have `nav-active` class. I am using following code but it is not working according to my requirements.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```js
$('ul li').find('li').click(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   $('li').removeClass('nav-active');
   $this.addClass('nav-active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav id="menu" class="nav-main" role="navigation">
 <ul class="nav nav-main">
  <li class="nav-parent item-b">
   <a href="#">
    <i class="icon icon-global" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span>Global</span>
   </a>

   <ul class="nav nav-children">
    <li class="item-a">
     <a href="#">
      <span>News</span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">
      <span>Highlights</span>
     </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-parent">
   <a href="#">
    <i class="icon icon-document-512"></i><span>My Documents</span>
   </a>
   <ul class="nav nav-children" id="menu1">
    <li>
     <a href="#">
      <span>My Download</span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">
      <span>My Wishlist</span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">
      <span>My New Documents</span></a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-parent"><!-- nav-expanded-->
    <a class="">
     <i class="icon icon-marketing-material" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <span>Marketing Material</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-children" id="menu1">
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <span>Batch Download</span>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <span>Upload</span>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <span>Edit/Delete</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="new-uploads.html";'>
        <span>New Uploads</span></a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="revision.html";'>
         <span>Revisions</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="top-download.html";'>
          <span>Top Downloads</span></a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>

       <li>
        <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="blank.html";'>
         <i class="icon icon-11111" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <span>GML Forum</span>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#"  onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="index - Copy.html";'>
         <i class="icon icon-market-research" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <span>Market Research</span>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">
         <i class="icon icon-market-access-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <span>Market Access</span>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">
         <i class="icon icon-compete" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <span>Competetive Intelligence</span>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">
         <i class="icon icon-portal" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <span>Portal Tutorial</span>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">
         <i class="icon icon-new-product-launch" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <span>New Product Launch</span>
        </a>
       </li>                                    
       <li class="nav-parent">
        <a href="#">
         <i class="icon icon-portal-admin"></i><span>Portal Administration</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-children" id="menu1">
         <li>
          <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="abbot-social-media.html";'>
           <span>Social Media</span>
          </a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>

       <li><hr class="separator" /></li>
       <li><a href="#"><i class="fa licon-calendar" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:24px;"></i>Upcoming Events</a></li
        ></ul>
       </nav>
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: please check the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you current example if you will do a **console.log($(this)**, it will show you **2** elements in the console if you have clicked a child element. One for the child element and one for its parent li element. This is called **event bubbling**. You need to take care of event bubbling by stop propagating the event.

Try this.

```js
$('li').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation()
   var $this = $(this);
   $('li').removeClass('nav-active');
   $this.addClass('nav-active');
});
```

```css
.nav-active a
{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu" class="nav-main" role="navigation">
                                <ul class="nav nav-main">
                                    <li class="nav-parent item-b">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <i class="icon icon-global" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            <span>Global</span>
                                        </a>

                                        <ul class="nav nav-children">
                                            <li class="item-a">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                     <span>News</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <span>Highlights</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-parent">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <i class="icon icon-document-512"></i><span>My Documents</span>
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="nav nav-children" id="menu1">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">
                                                     <span>My Download</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <span>My Wishlist</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <span>My New Documents</span></a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-parent"><!-- nav-expanded-->
                                        <a class="">
                                            <i class="icon icon-marketing-material" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            <span>Marketing Material</span>
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="nav nav-children" id="menu1">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">
                                                     <span>Batch Download</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <span>Upload</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <span>Edit/Delete</span></a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="new-uploads.html";'>
                                                    <span>New Uploads</span></a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="revision.html";'>
                                                    <span>Revisions</span></a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="top-download.html";'>
                                                    <span>Top Downloads</span></a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="blank.html";'>
                                            <i class="icon icon-11111" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            <span>GML Forum</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#"  onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="index - Copy.html";'>
                                            <i class="icon icon-market-research" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            <span>Market Research</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <i class="icon icon-market-access-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            <span>Market Access</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <i class="icon icon-compete" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            <span>Competetive Intelligence</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <i class="icon icon-portal" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            <span>Portal Tutorial</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <i class="icon icon-new-product-launch" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            <span>New Product Launch</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>                                    
                                    <li class="nav-parent">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <i class="icon icon-portal-admin"></i><span>Portal Administration</span>
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="nav nav-children" id="menu1">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="abbot-social-media.html";'>
                                                     <span>Social Media</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <li><hr class="separator" /></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa licon-calendar" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:24px;"></i>Upcoming Events</a></li
                                ></ul>
                            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to run the click function only once because when you click child element the parent element also gets clicked automatically right after that so `$(this)` ends up selecting parent item, everytime the child element gets clicked.

I added css for `.nav-active` class to show the code working. Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('nav li').one("click",function(){
     $('nav li').removeClass('nav-active');
     $(this).addClass('nav-active');
   })
})
```

```css
.nav-active>a>span{
  font-size:20px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu" class="nav-main" role="navigation">
 <ul class="nav nav-main">
  <li class="nav-parent item-b">
   <a href="#">
    <i class="icon icon-global" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span>Global</span>
   </a>

   <ul class="nav nav-children">
    <li class="item-a">
     <a href="#">
      <span>News</span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">
      <span>Highlights</span>
     </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-parent">
   <a href="#">
    <i class="icon icon-document-512"></i><span>My Documents</span>
   </a>
   <ul class="nav nav-children" id="menu1">
    <li>
     <a href="#">
      <span>My Download</span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">
      <span>My Wishlist</span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">
      <span>My New Documents</span></a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-parent"><!-- nav-expanded-->
    <a class="">
     <i class="icon icon-marketing-material" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <span>Marketing Material</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-children" id="menu1">
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <span>Batch Download</span>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <span>Upload</span>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <span>Edit/Delete</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="new-uploads.html";'>
        <span>New Uploads</span></a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="revision.html";'>
         <span>Revisions</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="top-download.html";'>
          <span>Top Downloads</span></a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>

       <li>
        <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="blank.html";'>
         <i class="icon icon-11111" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <span>GML Forum</span>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#"  onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="index - Copy.html";'>
         <i class="icon icon-market-research" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <span>Market Research</span>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">
         <i class="icon icon-market-access-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <span>Market Access</span>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">
         <i class="icon icon-compete" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <span>Competetive Intelligence</span>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">
         <i class="icon icon-portal" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <span>Portal Tutorial</span>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">
         <i class="icon icon-new-product-launch" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <span>New Product Launch</span>
        </a>
       </li>                                    
       <li class="nav-parent">
        <a href="#">
         <i class="icon icon-portal-admin"></i><span>Portal Administration</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-children" id="menu1">
         <li>
          <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("preview-frame").src="abbot-social-media.html";'>
           <span>Social Media</span>
          </a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>

       <li><hr class="separator" /></li>
       <li><a href="#"><i class="fa licon-calendar" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:24px;"></i>Upcoming Events</a></li
        ></ul>
       </nav>
```

Comment: okay I updated my answer. If it's working don't forget to accept it. you know click on the checkmark on the left of my answer